# Word VBA, end sub fails

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word vba that uses excel and has several procedures that call:

```
 private sub testsub1
     'some process

      call testsub2 (a, b, c,...)

 end sub

 private sub testsub2 (byref a as long, byref b as long, byref c as long,...)
     'some process

      call testsub3 (a, b, c,...)

 end sub

 private sub testsub3 (byref a as long, byref b as long, byref c as long,...)
     'some process

     'calls testub2 if a is less than some value.
      if a < somevalue then
         call testsub2 (a, b, c,...)
      end if

      documents("doc1").close    'closes a document
      wb.close 'closes a workbook
      exc.quit  'closes excel

      set wb = nothing
      set exc = nothing

      msgbox "Analysis complete"

 end sub
```

Question: I cannot end sub in testsub3 after calling testsub2 from testsub3. After MsgBox, it jumps to some code in testsub3 (documents("doc1").close)---error: bad file name         ------>document has already been closed.

But I am able to end if it did not call testsub2.

Ideas?

Thanks

Note: I don't use loop because the code is too long (error: procedure is too large). Hence the multiple procedures/sub.

Comment: Loop doesn't work here. Code is too long to put in one loop - causes error: procedure is too large. This is why I created multiple subs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this and worked, no errors

```
 private sub testsub3 (byref a as long, byref b as long, byref c as long,...)
     'some process

     'calls testub2 if a is less than some value.
      if a < somevalue then
         call testsub2 (a, b, c,...)

      else

         documents("doc1").close    'closes a document
         wb.close 'closes a workbook
         exc.quit  'closes excel

         set wb = nothing
         set exc = nothing

         msgbox "Analysis complete"

     end if

 end sub
```

Comment: I don't think you should `Call testsub2 (a,b,c,...)` from testsub3 if testsub2 calls testsub3 (as in your initial example). I expect your solution will fail as soon as `a < somevalue`. When that happens you will have a second instance of testsub2 running, which will start a new instance of testsub3, which will again find that `a < somevalue` and start a third instance of testsub2, etc.  I think you should instead say: `if a < somevalue then end sub` or create a new sub that does what you want done by the second instance of testsub2 (without calling testsub3 again...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like:

```
 Private analysisComplete As Boolean

 Private Sub testsub1()
     'some process

      analysisComplete = False

      Call testsub2(a, b, c,...)

 End Sub

 Private Sub testsub2(ByRef a As Long, ByRef b As Long, ByRef c As Long,...)
     'some process

      Call testsub3(a, b, c)

 End Sub

 Private Sub testsub3(ByRef a As Long, ByRef b As Long, ByRef c As Long,...)
     'some process

     'calls testub2 if a is less than some value.
      If a < someValue Then
         Call testsub2(a, b, c)
      End If

      If Not analysisComplete Then

        Documents("doc1").Close    'closes a document
        wb.Close 'closes a workbook
        exc.Quit  'closes excel

        Set wb = Nothing
        Set exc = Nothing

        MsgBox "Analysis complete"

        analysisComplete = True

    End If

 End Sub
```

So it executes the final portion of testsub3 only once.

Comment: This seems like it could cause the same issue he is currently experiencing unless all the data is sequential.

Comment: I am assuming sometime he gets out of the loop, and then the first testsub3 running (top of the stack) would close the document, then the following ones (lower in the stack) would not try to close the document again.

Comment: Right but he is doing something with the file and thus closing it will throw an error with something along the lines of `cannot do something when .... is closed`

Comment: brWHigino, I tried your code, but same error. For some reason, it still jumps back to documents("doc").close even if boolean analysisComplete = true...strange

Comment: engineersmnky, I am able to close documents("doc") successfully, but the problem occurs after MsgBox. After I close MsgBox, the error highlights the line documents("doc").close.